# 2sxc - change toolbar button color

Tags: 2sxc

How to change color of the blue toolbar buttons for editing?

I can't find the right css class to override this.

I also have problems how to "inspect" this hover buttons with chrome developer tools, is it posible to check calculated style of element when in hower state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
.sc-menu a div{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

In chrome developer tools I first found:
UL with sc-menu class and then disable "display: none"
in ".sc-element .sc-menu.sc-tb-show-hover"

After this it was easy to find the right class